# How to make selenium wait until the element is found instead of using time.sleep()

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

Basically the tittle, i'm building a small script to automate some basic stuff. I've been using time.sleep() to make the software wait a little until everything is loaded, but is there a better way to do this??

I want the script to wait as long as necessary by itself to make things faster and more clean.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from tkinter import *


def cs_update():

    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True



    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH,options = options) 
    driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
    driver.minimize_window()

    user_email = e.get()
    user_password = e2.get()

    driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")
    time.sleep(3)


    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mi cuenta")

    link.click()
    time.sleep(3)

    email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")

    email.send_keys(user_email)

    print("I sent the keys")
```

Comment: Actually, if your concern is the GUI not responding, the only way I could think of here is using `threading`, maybe import it first. I'm assuming your `cs_update()` is called from a button, then make its `command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=cs_update).start`. Might work. Or post bit more code, so we can look the `tkinter` part up better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.compraensanjuan.com")

timeout = 20 # set seconds to wait until TimeOutException raised
link = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Mi cuenta")))

link.click()

email = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "email")))
```

Comment: I'm reading the documentation now and wouldn't implicit wait be better in this case??

Comment: No, implicit wait is almost like `time.sleep()`. Fluent wait is better in almost every case, it will stop waiting after the element is found. E.g your website takes 3 seconds to load, you can write a fluent wait to find for it in 10 seconds. If it loads after 3 seconds, great, it will stop finding and do next action. If it still cannot find after 10 secs, it will raise Exception. But if you do `time.sleep(10)` it will always wait for 10 seconds, how long it takes for the page to load does not matter.